# iOS app rejected with reason 3.8 (inappropriate rating)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, wikipedia

I submitted a reference app, which has absolutely no offensive content in it. So I rated my app accordingly (4+). However, the app, as a convenience to users, provides reference urls to Wikipedia to save them some effort. For example, the app provides some data about a common item and if the user is curious about the item, I've provided a Wiki link to each item. User can click on it and access the wiki webpage without leaving the app.

Each wiki page displays a Search box at the top and the user can, obviously, type in anything they want there and access any material provided by Wikipedia. So I was asked to bump up the rating to 17+.

My question: Is there any way I can suppress the search box in Wikipedia? Or do anything in the iOS app to prevent user from leaving the original page?

If neither is possible, I suppose I could extract and embed relevant content from Wikipedia (with proper attribution). That would be too much effort, is static (unless updated periodically), and bloats the app with tens of MBs of data.

Note: I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911050/wikipedia-as-part-of-my-ios-app) that points to a github library to get and display a wiki page, but that still appears to expose a user to arbitrary Wiki content.

Comment: I think stackmonster means just up the rating of your app in the store!

Comment: I would have, if there was an option indicating the rating was due to web access. Unfortunately, the only way to trigger a 17+ rating is to indicate that the app has extreme graphic violence/nudity etc. Just didn't seem right that a reference app with boring data would have to make such claims and get a 17+ rating.

Comment: I just got my app rejected for this same reason. I launch a search not just a wiki and thus the user would be able to then search for anything. My issue is I can't figure out how to set the rating in iTunes connect. How does one set the rating when the app doesn't contain violence, etc? 
If I can't, I may try this wiki search box trick, but wouldn't this depend on wikipedia not changing its attributes?

Comment: The only way to set 17+ is to choose one of the options that trigger that rating. I considered that option and decided I didn't want to declare my app to have disturbing amounts of explicit sexual content and violence, to trigger a 17+ rating. Instead, I suppressed search and disabled links, and that was acceptable to the reviewer. My app was published with a rating of 4. That was a better compromise, even if it took a few extra days to wait for the review to complete (new binary). Once you declare your app to be 17+, I reckon it is going to be painful to try and get it rated down to 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To suppress the search box, something along these lines could work, to be put in the delegate of your `UIWebView`:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *js = "document.getElementById('mw-mf-search').style.display='none';";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

`mw-mf-search` is the id attribute of the search box on `m.wikipedia.org`.

To prevent leaving the page, you should implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and return `YES` only for resources such as images and sites you want to allow.